# How to redirect user to the page they were just at without them noticing?

Tags: return, redirect, back

The website viewer would be at page A, click a link that sends then to page B, but I want them to return to page A without them noticing.

When they click the link it changes the layout the viewer is browsing the site with, so the redirection code shouldn't erase or undo the cookies or whatever are stored with the link click.  Thanks!

Edit:
Here's what I'm doing. I have a page called setskin.php that has php code that takes header and footer codes for different layouts and applies them.  I don't know how to show code without it going crazy, so there's a screenshot of it here:

http://figmint.uuuq.com/Picture%202.png

I want to change my website so that in a sidebar there will be the same setskin options (so it will be on every page).  I was fiddling and managed to make it so when you click the link for the skin you want it changes the skin, but then you end up at the setskin.php page, which I don't want.  I was looking for a way to make it so it sends you to the setskin.php page (since I couldn't see how to change that) and then back to where you came from.

Comment: hmmm, which web programming language you are using? or you are talking about plain HTML?

Comment: Do you really need to go to the second page, or could you do the same thing using an innerframe?

Comment: Is there any specific purpose in having the link "send" them to page B (which bounces them right back), rather than having a click on the link just execute some Javascript which changes layout, sends an AJAX call to B if you're keen to do that, etc? The loading of B and redirect back to A would just be wasting two roundtrip-times plus, it seems to me.  Care to explain?

Comment: And BTW, when you do redirect, the noticing is inevitable -- the browser's address bar will tell the user what URL they're at, you can't trick it!-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX.  That way you can do whatever processing is needed behind the scenes with zero impact on the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referer header and return to that. But if that isn't set go to a default page?

Other options include putting the previous url as a parameter, like a 'next' parameter. Then redirect to that after you're done. Quite common pattern used for login.